# Dns records on directadmin for drupal site

Tags: drupal, dns, drupal-6

I've a drupal6 site and I use directadmin panel. My problem is that people can enter my site by;

```
www.mydomain.com
pop.mydomain.com
smtp.mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com
```

Why is it occuring? I know I can redirect all but I want to solve this problem.
Please help me..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have added multiple sub domains with `A` (or `CNAME`)records to the main domain.

Removing them will remove those unwanted sub domains. 
Also look for  wildcard pointers, for example, `*.domain.com`.

[image]

Comment: But they are exist on all of my domains and only one domain has a problem like this. I know that directadmin creates them automaticly. Also if I remove them, are mail service and ftp service work properly?

Comment: I added my dns record to my question.. I also use drupal boost module can it be a reason?

Comment: These A records just points the client to the specified IP. As long as you be MX records, emails will work. For FTP, your FTP software should be configured to listen to the correct domain. Try removing those sub domains.

Comment: I removed them and it looks like everything is ok. But I also remove MX record but mails are work properly I couldn't understand what happens. How can mail system works without MX record? And the real question, why directadmin create these A records if they are not required?